# PHP While and For Loop Grouping (using WP ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

Looping using a 'while' statment I get the following output:

```
move_it
clean_beauty
on_our_radar
move_it
```

I want to output these where the fields (for $featured_type) are the same. Eg. I want to output as follows:

```
move_it
move_it

clean_beauty

on_our_radar
```

Here is an example of the first example of what I currently output with a basic loop. I am looping through fields (from an Advanced Custom Field repeater in WordPress).

```
        while( has_sub_field( 'featured_posts', $acf_id )  ):


        $featured_post = get_sub_field( 'featured_post', $acf_id );
        $featured_type = get_field( 'editorial_template', $featured_post->ID );

        echo $featured_type . '<br />';

        endwhile;
```

I have written some code that does group but know there must be a more elegant way to achieve the same result. My way is clunky! Any advice appreciated.

```
        <?php 

        while( has_sub_field( 'featured_posts', $acf_id )  ):


        $featured_post = get_sub_field( 'featured_post', $acf_id );
        $featured_type = get_field( 'editorial_template', $featured_post->ID );


        if ($featured_type == 'move_it') {
            echo  $featured_type . '<br />';
        }

        endwhile;

        while( has_sub_field( 'featured_posts', $acf_id )  ):


        $featured_post = get_sub_field( 'featured_post', $acf_id );
        $featured_type = get_field( 'editorial_template', $featured_post->ID );


        if ($featured_type == 'clean_beauty') {
            echo $featured_type .  '<br />';
        }

        endwhile;

        while( has_sub_field( 'featured_posts', $acf_id )  ):


        $featured_post = get_sub_field( 'featured_post', $acf_id );
        $featured_type = get_field( 'editorial_template', $featured_post->ID );


        if ($featured_type == 'on_our_radar') {
            echo  $featured_type .  '<br />';
        }

     endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array you can store the values, then order and finally echo them:

```
$featured_types = array();

while( has_sub_field( 'featured_posts', $acf_id )  ):

    $featured_post = get_sub_field( 'featured_post', $acf_id );
    $featured_type = get_field( 'editorial_template', $featured_post->ID );

    $featured_types[] = $featured_type;

endwhile;

sort( $featured_types );

echo implode( '<br>', $featured_types );
```

If you don't want to order them alphabetically, there are [other ways](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) to do it.